# Adding libraries in Aurelia project

Tags: aurelia

I created a new project with the Aurelia cli but when I want to import a personnal library, the consol return an Unexpected token error.

I followed the [Adding Client Libraries to Your Project Tutorial](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6).

This is my library code :

```
export function hello{
    console.log("hello");
}
```

And in the aurelia.json file I added a new entry :

```
  {
    "name": "hello",
    "path": "../scripts/hello"
  },
```

I think this is a configuration problem in the transpiler entry, but i didn't find any informations.

```
  "transpiler": {
    "id": "babel",
    "displayName": "Babel",
    "fileExtension": ".js",
    "options": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
      ]
    },
    "source": "src/**/*.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, `bundles.dependencies` section of `aurelia.json` should be used for external libraries already transpilled to ES5 format.

1. Your could move your internal ES6 "library" into `src/` folder, so it would be transpilled along with the rest of your source code.
2. In case you want to create a shared library, you'll need a separate project for that, which provides an ES5 output.

In the latter case, [Aurelia Skeleton Plugin](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin) may give you fresh ideas. It is configured to provide multiple output formats.